# Count number of slashes in string with zsh

Tags: zsh

I try to get the number of slashes in a string with zsh. I thought it should work like this (replace all non / chars and then count them)

```
foo="sdfds/sf/sdf/sdf/sd/f//sdf/"
print ${#foo//[^/]/}
```

But i get `preexec:26: bad pattern: [^`. It seems to work for all characters except `/`. I tried to escape it with backslashes but it did not work until I added 3 backslashes:

```
print ${#foo//[^\\\/]/}
```

Why do I need to find an escaped slash in the string?

edit: Yes, it seems to work with one backslash using zsh -f.
My setopt:

```
autocd
autopushd
nobeep
completeinword
correct
extendedglob
extendedhistory
nohistbeep
histfindnodups
histignorealldups
histignoredups
histignorespace
histnofunctions
histnostore
histreduceblanks
histsavenodups
histverify
nohup
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
longlistjobs
monitor
nonomatch
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
sharehistory
shinstdin
transientrprompt
zle
```

Comment: That is strange. On my machine (*zsh* 5.2) I only need to escape the slash inside the pattern with a single backspace: `print ${#foo//[^\/]/}`. Does it work for you, if you start *zsh* without configuration: `zsh -f`. If so, could you please add the output of `setopt`?

Comment: So, I tested the options, but none of them seem to be the cause for this behavior. Do you get the same error message - "`bad pattern: [^`" - when trying to escape with a single or two backslashes? Which version of *zsh* are you using? And do you perchance have a link to your configuration?

Comment: @Adaephon i'm using the grml zsh config, or at least big parts of it: https://grml.org/zsh/

Comment: For me it works with the *grml zsh config*, with and without `.zshrc.local`. So the reason for this behavior is probably in the parts that are not from *grml*. BTW: What does `print ${#foo//[^\\\/]/}` show for `foo='a/b/c\x\y\z'` (Note the single quotes). In theory the pattern `[^\\\/]` should match any backslash (``\\``) or slash (`\/`), so it should print `5`, unless the two extra backlashes are actually needed to quote the single slash, than I would expect it to print `2`.

Comment: @Adaephon it gives me 5... So i do not really understand why this is needed...

Comment: Sorry, this may be a stupid question: but did you check in the meantime, whether the issue still persists? Otherwise I have no further idea about what may be the cause of this. This is really confusing.

Comment: @Adaephon I do not understand that either... The problem is still there. I assume my configuration is causing this trouble in some way. Do you any other way to find out whats causing it?

Comment: You can try bisecting your configuration. Assuming a monolithic `~/.zshrc`. Copy your `~/.zshrc` to another folder, e.g. `/tmp/zsh`. 1. From your shell run `ZDOTDIR=/tmp/zsh zsh`. 2. See if the behavior persists. 2a. If not, some other configuration file is at fault. 3. remove about the second half of the `.zshrc`. 4. repeat step (1.) 5. check if issue persists. 6a. If it does, remove the second half of the remaining config 6b. If it does not, re-add the first half of what you removed. 7. Rinse and repeat.